# Difference between two statements that declare an object

Tags: javascript, object, statements

What is the difference between this statement

```
var X = X || {};
```

And this. They do the same thing? There is a performance difference?

```
var X = typeof X === "undefined" ? {} : X;
```

Comment: Don't think there is performance diff. but first one is short.

Comment: One diff is that the first one checks if `X` is truthy, if it is not then `X` is an empty object. While the second one only checks for `undefined`.

Comment: Vasile, does one of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not the same.

The `||` will return the object when `X` is ***any*** possible [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.
The `typeof` check will *only* return `{}` if is `X` is `undefined`.

According to **[this test](http://jsperf.com/vs-undefined-check/2)**, the `undefined` check is nearly twice as fast. That's probably because no type casting is required.

Comment: Just commented that :)

Comment: And now I even added a jsperf to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case: `var X = X || {}` the `X` variable will be redefined if it's been declared but is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). So `var X = 0; X = X || {};` would overwrite the `0` with an object.